# email notification with custom email template

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, email, template

I need to send an email notification through SharePoint designer workflow and the body of the template will be dynamic it is coming from list.

Comment: Did you get it working? If you need more help than just inform me..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the list data from **ADD or Change Lookup** button after the below email template body.Pleas see below image.

[image]

**This is the example** where i added few list column names with their values coming from list.

**UPDATED**

You can see below image to get better idea.

[image]
You can get the item values from another list as well.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.but I have list with specific column with html format.how can we achive it

Comment: Is this fine for you? Or do you need something else?

Comment: In <html><td>...phone number </td></html> some thing like this

Comment: Yes you can put HTML content to the body. It will accept it.

Comment: Did you get the idea how to use dynamic data from list?

Comment: Ok ,I have sp list template custom list.in that I have column name called emailtemplateformate.value for emailtemplateformate will be like <table><td><phone number:></>

Comment: No don't have any idea

Comment: You can create your own HTML page whatever you need. Just blank the places where you need the values from the list.

Comment: <table><td>PhoneNumber:</td><td>put your cursor here & click the Add or Change Looup button & select the current item in first dropdown than select the field for Phone Number in second dropdown</td></table>

Comment: Kindly check here...http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/03/14/creating-html-emails-with-spd-workflows-aspx/

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to customize the email body with html using SPD, I would suggest selecting Advanced Properties on the email action and add your HTML template into the body section.

[image: Select the email action and click Advanced Properties under the modify section]

[image: Add your html template into the body section]

Answer (score 0):

Putting the html directly into your email like this **WON'T WORK**:

[image]

Instead, you need to create a string variable to hold your html, including any fields you want to include (with no spaces anywhere in the html) and use that variable in the email:

[image]