# Item content in OutLook email body

Tags: list, email, sharepoint-email

In SP 2010 OOTB if we select the item and click Email a "Link item URL", Item URL will be open in outlook body. Same way once user will select the item and click on Email a Link, I want that items data should open in outlook body and then user will manually type the email id and forward it. Need advice on this.

Comment: OOB the box you will need to use connect to Outlook and then forward the e-mail from there. Failing that look at third party Outlook integration.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a hyperlink field that is an email link with the body included. You'd have to write a workflow to set the value, and the workflow would have to run every time the is edited. I've given similar examples [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184021/email-notification-with-custom-email-template/184035#184035) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175535/can-i-trigger-a-workflow-from-a-hyperlink-in-a-list). For yours, you'd leave out the email address. So the link would look something like: `mailto:?subject=your subject&body=body text